# How to open compose email popup in sugarcrm on field?

Tags: backbone.js, sugarcrm, email

I have an text field in which we have shown the email address in task module of sugarcrm. Sugarcrm does not give us the option to create custom email field for any module. So I have shown email address in Text field.

When we open the record in the detail view then I want a link on that email field, So that user can click on that then the sugar inbuilt compose email popup open to send the email.

I have already set my profile email setting to sugarcrm email.

Thanks & Regards
Gaurav Sharma

Answer (score 0):

i did not try this, but i can give you an Idea, In contact module there is a `subpanel`  of Email when you click in `plus icon` on that `Email subpanel` it will  open a `popup` to send email.

You need a same concept for your `email field` , just try to open that `Create action` which is written on `subpanel` on your text field .
you will get success , you only need to write  a click even on  your `record.js` and call the , create action same as on `email subpanel`.